# What headers do I need for "PUT" request - Kinvey

Tags: javascript, ajax, kinvey

Hi everyone I make simple SPA application with JS and Kinvey. I have advertisements and every advert. must have views - how many times is seen(when "GET" request for that advert is called, another "PUT" request is called for the advert with increased views). The problem is that I can't figure out which headers to use: Authorization basic with username:pass and "Kinvey + authToken" return 401 Unauthorized. How to modify collection element which is not created by the currently logged in user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to use the Javascript SDK which means you don't have to do the quite complicated login / token generation process yourself.  It's not a Basic Auth system. The SDK's will handle everything for you.

You cannot by default modify elements that are not created by the logged-in user, which is of course a good idea for security reasons. But, in the Collection Settings, you can change the collection permissions from "Shared" to "Public" to allow anybody write access to any element.
If you want finer grained controls, you can use Business Logic to inspect ACLs at runtime: http://devcenter.kinvey.com/tutorials/using-acls